# How to stop runaway processes

Tags: iphone, multithreading, ios, race-condition

So I'm working on this application that requests and retrieves webservice content for iPhone.  The problem I am running into is this: When I initially request data, it is spawned off as an independent thread so that the application does not become unresponsive due to the network being slow.  What this means is that if the user navigates away from the current page before this data finishes downloading, unexpected things can happen.

I have managed to narrow down the problem cases to one relatively simple one:  I have some nested tables, so if a user goes down into the "Messages" table, which can sometimes take a little while to download, then back out immediately, and select a different set of messages to view, the previous set of messages ends up loading, because it was still in the queue.

Here are things I have tried:

1) I tried cancelling the operations, but this is futile, because since I only allow one operation in the queue at the time, it triggers immediately

2) I tried validating that the recipient of the data is the same, but this doesn't work because the actual table object is the between the two selections, it just needs a different data set.

Anyone have any general programming suggestions on how to solve this tricky threading problem?

On an iPhone specific note: if I could just stop the user from being able to back out of the messages table, I wouldn't have this problem, because they would basically be locked into that view until the data has finished loading.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a reference for the thread? If you have a reference for the thread, then you can interrupt it... of course it's probably better to wait for the thread to complete whatever it's doing, but that depends on the workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/downloading-images-for-table-without.html) has some design advice relating to iOS networking and threading. The basic gist of it is "Don't use explicit threading", and I couldn't agree more. [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003755) has great built-in functionality for asynchronously loading data from a URL while managing all of the threading for you. They can also be cancelled easily at will.

If you were to use the NSURLConnection paradigm, you can simply cancel any pending request when you back out of the requesting view controller.

Comment: The real problem I"m having is that the requests are no longer pending, they are in the process of downloading when this switch occurs.  Can I still cancel the request if it is already started?

Comment: The code I was using did use NSUrlConnection, but it spawned its own thread, then used synchronous requests within that thread.  It was a fairly simple change to make it all on one thread, but perform the request asynchronously, and I was able to cancel it with no problems.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Great, that's exactly what you want: Asynchronous on the main thread vs synchronous in a background thread. Glad it's working.